# how to use 'like' instead of '=' in magento collection filter for custom module

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have managed to do this with `addFieldToFilter` default functionality like this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('first_name','last_name'),
    array($post['firstName'],$post['lastName'])             
);
```

this is working when i print sql (this is just part from the whole statement being printed):

```
((first_name = 'r') OR (last_name = 't'))
```

now i am trying to understand how to use `'like'` instead of `=`.
need some help in understanding that.

your time and answers are highly appericiated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you googlers, the rigth way to to it is:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    array('first_name','last_name'),
    array(
        array('like' => '%'.$post['firstName'].'%'),
        array('like' => '%.'$post['lastName'].'%')
    )             
);
```

You should pass an array of fields and an array of conditions.

Generated SQL:

```
... WHERE ((first_name LIKE '%xxxx%') OR (last_name LIKE '%yyy%')) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

It's weird, but after some researching into your question the solution is quite simple - it's given in the comments in the Magento code:

In the comment for the method `addAttributeToFilter()` in `Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php` (which finally gets called) you can read:

```
/**
 * Add attribute filter to collection
 *
 * If $attribute is an array will add OR condition with following format:
 * array(
 *     array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>'test%'),
 *     array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>'test%'),
 * )
 */
```

Wasn't quite clear to me what this was supposed to mean, but it's as simple: If you want to add an OR condition between the attributes in your statement, then you have to give your parameter for the `addAttributeToFilter()` method in this way, so in your case:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
array(
   array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>$post['firstName']),
   array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>$post['lastName'])
));
```

You can follow this if you look inside the `addAttributeToFilter()` method:

```
if (is_array($attribute)) {
        $sqlArr = array();
        foreach ($attribute as $condition) {
            $sqlArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition, $joinType);
        }
        $conditionSql = '('.implode(') OR (', $sqlArr).')';
```

Comment: actually my module doesn't based on eav based model i have tried to use the code you mentioned it gives the output like this: `((Array = '') OR (Array = ''))` guess i have to keep trying or find another way.

Comment: I don't really understand, how do you retrieve your collection?

Comment: `$collection = Mage::getModel('eventsmgr/eventsmgr')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter(
                        array('venue','title'),
                        array('lahore','First event')
                 );` before using what you have suggested. actually i have tried that too but didn't happen :(

Comment: with that in sql statement `SELECT 'main_table'.* FROM 'eventsmgr' AS 'main_table' WHERE ((venue = 'lahore') OR (title = 'First event'))` i get this.

Comment: `Mage::getModel('eventsmgr/eventsmgr')` refers to a third party modul? You should trace down, where it gets the `addFieldToFilter()` method from and examine the latter.

Answer (score 2):

```
addFieldToFilter( 'sku', array( "like"=>'abc123' ) )
```

Here you can read much more about Magento collections: http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections

For example, see section named *"AND or OR, or is that OR and AND?"* in this article.

Comment: yes this will work for only one field but i am looking to make it work in the above case (using two fields). thanks for the link.